# python stdlib not found or stdlib found without .py files

Tags: python, windows, eclipse, pydev

i have eclipse installed on windows 7. I installed pydev plugin for eclipse but when i am specifying the interpreter path it says python stdlib not found or stdlib found without .py files

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your Python interpreter does not have .py files, you can use a Python interpreter from http://python.org which does have .py files... (or just copy over the .py files from the lib in that interpreter on top of your current one, although this could be more dangerous).